# Issue with sort() using the < for my class

Tags: c++, sorting

The code I'm working with comes from Ivor Horton's "**Beginning Visual C++ 2010**". 
Specifically Ex10_02.cpp using the Person.h.

The `sort` function does not work on my class objects. When names are entered and Enter key is finally pressed, the list of names is output in the order given in the input and after the sort() function is called, the names are again output to the screen. They should be sorted based on the second name. But they are output in the same order that I enter them initially.

I get no compile errors. I have tested the operator<() for my class and it works when comparing two objects of the class Person. But again the sort() function for the vector of Person objects is not correctly working. I don't have any more ideas on why this is happening. Any insight would be welcomed.

The code is as follows:

```
// Ex10_02
// storing objects in a vector

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<Person> people;                 // Vector of Person objects
    const size_t maxlength(50);
    char firstname[maxlength];
    char secondname[maxlength];
    vector<int> numbers;

    // input all the people
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Enter a first name or press Enter to end:";
        cin.getline(firstname, maxlength, '\n');
        if(strlen(firstname) == 0)
            break;
        cout << "Enter the second name: ";
        cin.getline(secondname, maxlength, '\n');
        people.push_back(Person(firstname, secondname));
    }

    // Output the contents of the vector
    cout << endl;
    auto iter(people.begin());
    while(iter != people.end())
        iter++->showPerson();

sort(people.begin(), people.end());
    cout << endl;
    for(auto i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
   {
      people[i].showPerson();
   }

   cout << endl;
   for(auto i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
   {
      people[i].showPerson();
   }
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Is people[0] < people[1] ?" << endl;
   if(people[0] < people[1])
   {
       cout << "YES" << endl;
       people[0].showPerson ();
       people[1].showPerson();
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "NO" << endl;
       people[1].showPerson();
       people[0].showPerson();
   }
   cout << endl;
   int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
  vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);               // 32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33
   for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    cout << myvector[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;
    // using default comparison (operator <):
    sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());           //(12 32 45 71)26 80 53 33
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    cout << myvector.at(i) << endl;
    return 0;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`Person.h`:

```
// A class defining people by their names
//#pragma once
#ifndef PERSON_H_INCLUDED
#define PERSON_H_INCLUDED    
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    // Constructor, includes no-arg constructor
    Person(const char* first = "John", const char*  second = "Doe")
    {
        initName(first, second);
    }
    // Copy constructor
    Person(const Person& p)
    {
        initName(p.firstname, p.secondname);
    }
    // Destructor
    ~Person()
    {
        delete[] firstname;
        delete[] secondname;
    }
    // Assignment operator
    Person& operator =(const Person& p)
    {
        // deal with p = p assignment situation
        if(&p == this)
        {
            return *this;

            delete[] firstname;
            delete[] secondname;
            initName(p.firstname, p.secondname);
            return *this;
        }
    }
        // Less-than operator
        bool operator <(const Person& p)
        {
            int result(strcmp(secondname, p.secondname));
            if(result < 0 || result == 0 && strcmp(firstname, p.firstname) < 0)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        // output a person
        void showPerson() const
        {
            cout << firstname << " " << secondname << endl;
        }

private:
    char* firstname;
    char* secondname;

    // private helper function to avoid code duplication
    void initName(const char* first, const char* second)
    {
        size_t length(strlen(first)+1);
        firstname = new char[length];
        strcpy_s(firstname, length, first);
        length = strlen(second) + 1;
        secondname = new char[length];
        strcpy_s(secondname, length, second);
    }
};
#endif // PERSON_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: The condition in your `operator<` function is equal to `result < 0 || (result == 0 && result < 0)`. You don't see any problem with it?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute your code, one line at a time, including the sort function and its calls to your custom comparison operator, what observations did you make? You do know how to use your debugger, to fully analyze your program's execution, right? After all, knowing how to use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Here's a tip to help you find your bug: a working comparison operator is not enough for `sort()` to work correctly. For example, if the vector is out of order, the `sort()` function needs to be able to swap the elements. That means using the assignment operator. Now, keep staring at your assignment operator, until you see your bug.

Comment: Well, I have looked at that many times. And from what I can glean   result = (strcmp(secondname, p.secondname)); which means that if this.secondname is closer to "A" than p.secondname then result will be less than 0. if they are equal result will be 0 and if this.secondname past p.secondname than result will be > 0..

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Don't you mean *bug**s***?

Comment: Look closer at `result == 0 && result < 0`. When will that *ever* be true?

Comment: Your assignment operator only returns a value when self-assigning. It doesn't do anything at all when you're not self-assigning.

Comment: The code for `Person` would be a third as long if it used `std::string` instead of `char*`. It wouldn't need a user-written assignment operator or a destructor and the `<` operator would be one line long.

Answer (score 1):

Change your assignment operator like this:

```
// Assignment operator
Person& operator =(const Person& p)
{
    // deal with p = p assignment situation
    if (&p != this)
    {

        delete[] firstname;
        delete[] secondname;
        initName(p.firstname, p.secondname);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

You have wrong `&p == this` check, return too early and no return path on the else path (at the end).

And your comparison operator like already pointed by @StoryTeller to:

```
if (result < 0 || ( result == 0 && strcmp(firstname, p.firstname) < 0 ))
```

You can also make your comparison operator `const`, use `std::string` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I would have never looked at the assignment operator.

Comment: Because you have list of non-movable objects `sort` just moves them around by assigning new values